# MS Access: use VBA to split a string from a text box into other text boxes

Tags: ms-access, split, vba

I want to split a string in a textbox into many text boxes each box containing one word using vba in Access

so lets say the text box name `text1` and it contains a string like `hello I'm asking a question`

I want to split that string into text boxes so it would be like

```
text2 = hello
text3 = I'm
text4 = asking
 ...etc
```

is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: yes, there is. split the textbox value by space into an array, and go through it with a while/for each. the loop's core should CreateControl (see ms help) a new text box, add n-th array element as it's text and this is it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat solution found: [ParseWord() Function](http://allenbrowne.com/func-10.html)

The code below is a bit lengthy, but is easy to use once implemented.
What this code does is it creates a function within your database project. This function is called: ParseWord(). It is not a built-in function. Hence why you need to add the code to a module in your database project.

```
Function ParseWord(varPhrase As Variant, ByVal iWordNum As Integer, Optional strDelimiter As String = " ", _
    Optional bRemoveLeadingDelimiters As Boolean, Optional bIgnoreDoubleDelimiters As Boolean) As Variant
On Error GoTo Err_Handler 'I COMMENTED THIS OUT AND THE REFERENCE AT THE BOTTOM
    'Purpose:   Return the iWordNum-th word from a phrase.
    'Return:    The word, or Null if not found.
    'Arguments: varPhrase = the phrase to search.
    '           iWordNum = 1 for first word, 2 for second, ...
    '               Negative values for words form the right: -1 = last word; -2 = second last word, ...
    '               (Entire phrase returned if iWordNum is zero.)
    '           strDelimiter = the separator between words. Defaults to a space.
    '           bRemoveLeadingDelimiters: If True, leading delimiters are stripped.
    '               Otherwise the first word is returned as null.
    '           bIgnoreDoubleDelimiters: If true, double-spaces are treated as one space.
    '               Otherwise the word between spaces is returned as null.
    'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com. June 2006.
    Dim varArray As Variant     'The phrase is parsed into a variant array.
    Dim strPhrase As String     'varPhrase converted to a string.
    Dim strResult As String     'The result to be returned.
    Dim lngLen As Long          'Length of the string.
    Dim lngLenDelimiter As Long 'Length of the delimiter.
    Dim bCancel As Boolean      'Flag to cancel this operation.

    '*************************************
    'Validate the arguments
    '*************************************
    'Cancel if the phrase (a variant) is error, null, or a zero-length string.
    If IsError(varPhrase) Then
        bCancel = True
    Else
        strPhrase = Nz(varPhrase, vbNullString)
        If strPhrase = vbNullString Then
            bCancel = True
        End If
    End If
    'If word number is zero, return the whole thing and quit processing.
    If iWordNum = 0 And Not bCancel Then
        strResult = strPhrase
        bCancel = True
    End If
    'Delimiter cannot be zero-length.
    If Not bCancel Then
        lngLenDelimiter = Len(strDelimiter)
        If lngLenDelimiter = 0& Then
            bCancel = True
        End If
    End If

    '*************************************
    'Process the string
    '*************************************
    If Not bCancel Then
        strPhrase = varPhrase
        'Remove leading delimiters?
        If bRemoveLeadingDelimiters Then
            strPhrase = Nz(varPhrase, vbNullString)
            Do While Left$(strPhrase, lngLenDelimiter) = strDelimiter
                strPhrase = Mid(strPhrase, lngLenDelimiter + 1&)
            Loop
        End If
        'Ignore doubled-up delimiters?
        If bIgnoreDoubleDelimiters Then
            Do
                lngLen = Len(strPhrase)
                strPhrase = Replace(strPhrase, strDelimiter & strDelimiter, strDelimiter)
            Loop Until Len(strPhrase) = lngLen
        End If
        'Cancel if there's no phrase left to work with
        If Len(strPhrase) = 0& Then
            bCancel = True
        End If
    End If

    '*************************************
    'Parse the word from the string.
    '*************************************
    If Not bCancel Then
        varArray = Split(strPhrase, strDelimiter)
        If UBound(varArray) >= 0 Then
            If iWordNum > 0 Then        'Positive: count words from the left.
                iWordNum = iWordNum - 1         'Adjust for zero-based array.
                If iWordNum <= UBound(varArray) Then
                    strResult = varArray(iWordNum)
                End If
            Else                        'Negative: count words from the right.
                iWordNum = UBound(varArray) + iWordNum + 1
                If iWordNum >= 0 Then
                    strResult = varArray(iWordNum)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    '*************************************
    'Return the result, or a null if it is a zero-length string.
    '*************************************
    If strResult <> vbNullString Then
        ParseWord = strResult
    Else
        ParseWord = Null
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler: 'I COMMENTED OUT THESE 4 LINES
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, "ParseWord()")
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Once you add the function to a module into your database, you will be able to call it in your VBA code just like a built in function.

Example (On click event):

[image]

I also had to comment out the "On Error GoTo Err_Handler" Lines since I didn't have those set up. (I referenced these in the code)

Comment: thank you so much your code works like charm it does the job as expected I don't have error handler too so I removed these lines thanks again :)

Comment: Not my code. Credit the site. I just discovered this code as well and I'll be sure to remember it if I ever need it. Glad to help!

Comment: even if its not yours it helped me so much I've been trying to figure it out for so many days I even googled it with no luck so thank you for your help

Answer (score 6):

Access has a built in split() command that will do this.

So, this code will work:

```
Dim v        As Variant
Dim sOne     As Variant
Dim i        As Integer

v = Split(Me.TextBox0, " ")
i = 0
For Each sOne In v
   i = i + 1
   Me("text" & i) = sOne
Next
```

So above would take the string from a textbox0 on a form, and put say 3 values into textbox 1 to 3.

So a large whack of code is not required.